# How to get all generic names in the API (drug label)

Tags: data-request, api, openfda

I want list of all generic names in the api.fda. I have this end point query giving me first 1000 generic names. 
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000

Thats only 1000. How do I page through all of it. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

According to the open FDA [query parameters help page](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/), you should combine the `skip` parameter with the `limit` parameter.

> `skip`: Skip this number of records that match the search parameter, then return the matching records that follow. **Use in combination with `limit` to paginate results**.

-from https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

you can just put the limit higher and get oll 34129

```
 url='https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000000'
 j<-fromJSON(url)
 j$results %>% nrow()

 [1] 34129
```